# Do you have to use the microkernel?

Tags: scala, akka, remoting

I've been looking into examples for akka remoting and they all use the `Bootable` trait, which I understand is part of the microkernel. The project that I'm working on doesn't use the microkernel/`Bootable`, and I can't get remote actor creation to work.

I'm wondering, do you have to use the microkernel for remote actor creation to work? Does the microkernel provide anything besides allowing you choices of main classes to boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The microkernel just generates helper scripts to assist in deployment more easily, but you can use Akka remoting without it.

Comment: My problem was that I pulled an actor from one project into a clean new one. In the old project, the actor had a long path (`/parent1/parent2/actor`) but in the new project it was a short path (`/actor`). Since the paths were different, it was creating it locally instead of remotely.